# How to Restore DB2 Icon on System Tray

Tags: db2

I closed the DB2 system tray icon in Windows XP and now I can't figure out how to restore it.

It doesn't reappear on reboot even.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Answer (score 1):

DB2 icon sometimes doesn’t show on system tray. 
To restore this as previously, run this command on command prompt:

```
db2systray +auto
```

Hope this solve your problem!